# PostgreSQL CPU 100% after configure Wal log shipping hot standby

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, postgresql-12, debian, troubleshooting

I have configured Hight Avaliabily WAL Log Shipping Hot Standby (SSL) with one node. But after I configure, both hosts (primary and secondary) take 100% CPU usage.

The most strange is because I have only one database called "TESTE" with one table called "EXAMPLE" to check if replication was OK. The replication worked perfectly but I don't understand why my CPU takes 100% usage because I don't have any application connect on my cluster.

I ran HTOP command and get this results:

Image 1 - Primary Server HTOP Info

[image: Image 1 - Primary Server HTOP info]

Image 2 - Secondary Server HTOP info

[image: Image 2 - Secundary Server HTOP info]

S.O. version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

PostgreSQL version:

```
postgres (PostgreSQL) 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1)
```

Primary server postgres.conf file:

```
max_connections = 100
SSL = on
shared_buffers = 2GB
work_mem = 10485kb
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix
effective_io_concurrency = 200
max_worker_processes = 4
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 2
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
max_parallel_workers = 4
wal_level = replica
wal_buffers = 16MB
max_wal_size = 200MB
min_wal_size = 80MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
archive_mode = on
max_wal_senders = 3
wal_keep_segments = 8
hot_standby = on
hot_standby_feedback = on
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_cache_size = 6GB
default_statistics_target = 100
```

pg_stat_activity info:

[image]

pg_stat_archiver info:

[image]

pg_stat_replication info:
[image]

**If I stop postgres service in both servers the CPU still has 100% usage.**

Anyone can help me?

Comment: That command looks like as if you have been hacked. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617329) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63354287) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149034)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is it worth trying to change all passwords? It's a new cluster with no data

Comment: Disconnect all servers from the internet, get rid of the malware, then re-configure Postgres to not allow connections with the superuser account from the outside. And then, yes, use secure passwords or SSH

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But in this case, I use a cloud (IaaS). If I disconnect servers from the internet I lose my connection.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you post an answer to my question? It's really a malware. If you can post some safety tips and related articles to enrich the answer, I think it would be interesting for future readers.

Comment: If there is no data, what is the point of trying to salvage it?  Just throw it away and stand up new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By exposing a database with a weak superuser password to the internet you invited somebody to break in and use your CPU for their own purposes, probably [mining crypto-currencies](https://www.hackread.com/hackers-hide-monero-cryptominer-in-scarlett-johansson-picture/).

Take the machine from the internet, wipe it clean and re-install the operating system. In the case of a hosted database, decommission the database and get a new one.

To protect yourself from this problem, choose good passwords.