# Almost 100% CPU Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, cpu

When I restart Postgresql 11, the CPU shows basically no CPU usage. But after a while the CPU is occupied by "kdevtmpfsi". What is this and how can I fix this?

```
1275    postgres    99.8 %  /tmp/kdevtmpfsi
```

Comment: You have been hacked. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149034/user-postgres-launches-process-that-takes-all-cpus-100-usage) or [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214824/mysterious-postgres-process-pegging-cpu-at-100-no-running-queries) or [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/273999/postgresql-cpu-100-after-configure-wal-log-shipping-hot-standby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151640/kdevtmpfsi-using-the-entire-cpu

you should check the various possibilities described there
but:
https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/217
"...This is not a redis issue. This is a known crypto mining malware unrelated to redis..."

google kdevtmpfsi, the results seem to indicate mining malware...